# Laravel 5.0 is having issue with Predis dependency

Tags: php, laravel-5, redis

While running composer update. I am geting this error list. Kindly suggest me solution as soon as possible.

> Problem 1
>       - illuminate/support v5.5.2 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.5.17 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.5.16 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.5.0 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.4.9 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.4.36 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.4.27 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.4.19 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.4.17 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.4.13 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.4.0 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.3.4 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.3.23 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.3.16 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.3.0 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - illuminate/support v5.2.25 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.9) does not satisfy that requirement.
>       - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.0.35
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.34
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.33
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.32
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.31
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.0.30
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.29
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.28
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.27
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.26
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.25
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.24
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.23
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.22
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.21
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.20
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.19
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.18
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.17
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.16
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.15
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.13
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.12
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.11
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.10
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.9
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.8
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.6
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.5
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.4
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.3
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.2
>       - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.1
>       - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar v2.4.0 requires illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22,
>   v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0,
>   v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28,
>   v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0,
>   v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27,
>   v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2].
>       - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar v2.4.1 requires illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22,
>   v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0,
>   v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28,
>   v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0,
>   v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27,
>   v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2].
>       - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar v2.4.2 requires illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22,
>   v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0,
>   v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28,
>   v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0,
>   v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27,
>   v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2].
>       - barryvdh/laravel-debugbar v2.4.3 requires illuminate/support 5.1.*|5.2.*|5.3.*|5.4.*|5.5.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/support[v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22,
>   v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30, v5.1.31, v5.1.41, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0,
>   v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28,
>   v5.2.31, v5.2.32, v5.2.37, v5.2.43, v5.2.45, v5.2.6, v5.2.7, v5.3.0,
>   v5.3.16, v5.3.23, v5.3.4, v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.17, v5.4.19, v5.4.27,
>   v5.4.36, v5.4.9, v5.5.0, v5.5.16, v5.5.17, v5.5.2].
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.41|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.43|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.45|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>       - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.0.30, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.10, v5.0.11,
>   v5.0.12, v5.0.13, v5.0.14, v5.0.15, v5.0.16, v5.0.17, v5.0.18,
>   v5.0.19, v5.0.2, v5.0.20, v5.0.21, v5.0.22, v5.0.23, v5.0.24, v5.0.25,
>   v5.0.26, v5.0.27, v5.0.28, v5.0.29, v5.0.3, v5.0.31, v5.0.32, v5.0.33,
>   v5.0.34, v5.0.35, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9].
>       - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-debugbar ~2.4 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-debugbar[v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2,
>   v2.4.3].

Comment: You need to upgrade your PHP to v7.0

Comment: I am using laravel 5.0, and in its official documentation they have mention the version is comaptible PHP >= 5.4, PHP < 7 and with this predis extension too. https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues

Comment: You are using laravel 5.5.x .. Use this command and check the version `php artisan -V`

Comment: I am confirmed. It is version 5.0.35 only.

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar" : "~2.4" in composer.json. I was getting the issue. After removing this issue got resolved.